# How to install sudo package in Unix?

Tags: sudo, root

I'm new to this `sudo` command. I needed to do `sudo mount -o remount`. But it is giving me the following message

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

So I assume, it is not installed on my server. Could anyone give me instructions on how to properly install the `sudo` package on my server. I followed this tutorial [http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/sudo.html][1]. But I am not able to login as a `root` and run command `make install`.

My actual problem is: I have phpseclib installed on `/usr/share/pear`. I want to send some file using `phpseclib` from one website to another one.(I'll generate pdf files on website1 and send pdf files to website2) I have a test.php outside of `wordpress`, it works perfectly (mean by I can see contents of website2 using ssh on website1). 
But then I have a wordpress page, it has exact same code, it said it failed to open library. I asked on other stackoverflow question and the member said because /usr/share/pear only allow root to access. As a wordpress user, I don't have a privilege. So that is why am I here and was trying to gain root access.

Comment: Wrong question: you have sudo installed, but it's not configured to do anything useful. Sudo is a common way of executing commands as root, but not the only one. You need another way to gain root (if only because that's necessary if you want to set up sudo). What distribution is this?

Comment: As @Gilles said, you have sudo installed, but you need root access to modify the /etc/sudoers file to grant permission to your userid to run the mount command.

Comment: What are the other ways to gain access to root? What is distribution? Sorry I am not familiar with it. I just have web server and web site running on wordpress. I installed phpseclib on /usr/share/pear. But my wordpress page cannot access since it said only root can access it. I have test.php outside of worpress, it can access my phpseclib just fine.

Comment: @user2090076 a few examples of distributions: Ubuntu, Debian, Red Hat (aka RHEL), CentOS, OpenSUSE... the list goes on. if you really don't know, run `lsb_release` (it it's available) or `cat /etc/*-release`, which should give you a hint.

Comment: @strugee I think mine is UNIX. Thank you for the info.

Comment: @user2090076 "UNIX" is literally the broadest thing you could say. GNU/Linux is UNIX-like, so all GNU/Linux distributions are UNIXes (although some will disagree with that use of the term). _please_ be more specific - it will probably help you to look up "linux distribution" on Wikipedia, so you can actually understand what people (including you!) are talking about.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsb_release -ic`, that should tell us what system you are running, if the command does not exist, that will also narrow things down.

Comment: @terdon -bash: lsb_release: command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have an account on a unix system, there are two main ways to gain administrative privileges:

- with `su`, which requires knowing the password to the root account;
- with `sudo`, which requires having prior authorization and typing your account's password.

Many variations are possible (other tools, other authentication methods), but if you haven't configured anything special, one of these is likely to work. Depending on the distribution, `su` or `sudo` may be the default way.

If you're using the command line, you can type:

- `su -c 'somecommand'` or `sudo somecommand` to execute a command as root;
- `su` or `sudo -s` to execute a shell as root;
- `su -` or `sudo -i` to execute a shell as root, with root's initialization files.

GUI environments have ways to run commands as root by invoking `su` or `sudo` under the hood and prompting the user for a password in a dialog box.

If `sudo` tells you “no valid sudoers sources found”, it means that the sudo program is installed, but not configured. You won't be able to use it until you've configured it, and you need root access for that. Always run the `visudo` command to set up `sudo`, never try to edit its configuration file directly. Before running `visudo`, make sure that you've configured your default editor — check that the value of the `VISUAL` environment variable is something you're comfortable with (if unset, it may default to vi), e.g. `export VISUAL=nano`.

To gain root access, run `su` and type the root password. It is rare for `su` to be disabled. Many systems make `su` to root inoperative indirectly, by not having a root password.

Since `sudo` isn't set up, it's highly likely that `su` is. If it isn't, this is an unusual set up; check your hosting provider's documentation or contact their support.

Comment: I am getting this message `visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied`

Comment: @user2090076 You need to run this as root, of course. Your first step is to figure out how to get root access. If you need help with that, read your hosting provider's documentation or contact their support. We really can't help you more without more information from you.

Comment: I contacted my hosting provider, but they said my web site is running on shared server, so I cannot have a root access. That means do I need to have dedicated server?

Comment: @user2090076 Indeed, on a shared server, you wouldn't get root access. I can't tell you whether you need to have a dedicated server: you never said why you really needed to have root access. You should ask a new question, explaining what you need to do with `/usr/share/pear`. Tell us what you tried (copy-paste commands, file contents, etc.), what happened (copy-paste error messages, etc.), and what you wanted to happen instead.

Comment: @user2090076 Ask a new question. (This may be a question for [wordpress.se] rather than [unix.se], I don't know whether the software you're having problems with is part of Wordpress.) Be sure to give all the facts (you wrote a lot more in your comment here than in your question). Link to the SO question, too.